# I get namespace error

Tags: php, namespaces

Am learning how namespace works and have three files:- index, iClass, and iClassed

**iClass.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\ic;

class iClass {
    public static function callMeFromClass() {
        echo 'OK - you have called me!';
        exit;
    }
}
```

**iClassed.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\icl;

class iClass {
    public static function callMe() {
        echo 'OK - iclassed - you have called me!';
        exit;
    }
}
```

and the index.php

```
<?php
namespace inex;

require_once 'iClass.php';
require_once 'iClassed.php';

use app\ic\iClass;
iClass::callMeFromClass();

use app\icl\iClass;
iClass::callMe();
```

The error that I get after I try to run is

> Cannot use app\icl\iClass as iClass because the name is already in use
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\namespace\index.php on line 10

Can somebody explain why the error.

Comment: Sure, you try to import two classes under the same local name `iClass`, that obviously is not possible. Either use the fully qualified class name (namespaced name) or import them under different names.

Comment: you can use different class name

Comment: @arkascha, am new to it .. can you please let me know how do i use a fully qualified class name or import them under different name .. i'd like to accept your answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you try to import two classes under the same local name iClass, that obviously is not possible. Either use the fully qualified class name (namespaced name) or import them under different names.

Using a fully qualified class name would mean:

```
\app\ic\iClass::callMe();
\app\icl\iClass::callMe();
```

Or you "use" the classes under a different local name:

```
use app\ic\iClass;
use app\icl\iClass as iClassed; 

iClass::callMeFromClass();
iClassed::callMe();`
```

I suggest you start reading the documentation of the things you use. It is of great quality and comes with good examples: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php